# Getting Result From node.js multipleStatements query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I have the following `node.js` code executing the `SQL` below it via the `mysql` module, however it is printing `null` to the `console` even when the `SQL` itself executed manually under the same `MySQL` user account returns the expected value.  Is there something I'm missing in the execution of this to retrieve the appropriate result?

```
let wipeSQL = fs.readFileSync('./inc/sql/wipedb.sql', 'utf8').replace('%%DATABASE_NAME%%', conf['databasedatabase']);
conn.query(wipeSQL, (err, results, fields) => {
    if (err) {
        conn.destroy();
        reject (false);
        return;
    }
    console.log(results[results.length - 1][0]['@procedures'], fields[fields.length - 1]);
    resolve();
});
```

---

```
USE `%%DATABASE_NAME%%`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

SET @procedures = '';
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `', routine_schema, '`.`', routine_name, '`') SEPARATOR ';')
INTO
    @procedures
FROM
    information_schema.ROUTINES R
WHERE
    R.ROUTINE_TYPE = "PROCEDURE" AND
    R.ROUTINE_SCHEMA = '%%DATABASE_NAME%%';

SET @procedures = CONCAT(@procedures, ';');

SET @functions = '';
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `', routine_schema, '`.`', routine_name, '`') SEPARATOR ';')
INTO
    @functions
FROM
    information_schema.ROUTINES R
WHERE
    R.ROUTINE_TYPE = "FUNCTION" AND
    R.ROUTINE_SCHEMA = '%%DATABASE_NAME%%';

SET @functions = CONCAT(@functions, ';');
SET @procedures = CONCAT(@procedures, @functions);

SET @tables = '';
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', table_schema, '`.`', table_name, '`'))
INTO
    @tables
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    table_schema = '%%DATABASE_NAME%%';

SET @tables = IF(@tables IS NULL, 'SET @tables = NULL;', CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', @tables, ';'));

PREPARE stmt FROM @tables;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

SELECT @procedures;
```

The purpose is to work around an issue in `MySQL` which prevents deleting `functions` and `stored procedures` from dynamic `SQL` and from within another `stored procedure`, requiring that I return the things to be dropped and then execute those as a separate statement.  A solution to drop those `functions` and `stored procedures` would work just as well, but I don't expect it to exist (this is a port from `PHP`, in which the multiple statement return works well.  Console output, if it helps:

```
null [ FieldPacket {
    catalog: 'def',
    db: '',
    table: '',
    orgTable: '',
    name: '@procedures',
    orgName: '',
    charsetNr: 33,
    length: 50331645,
    type: 250,
    flags: 0,
    decimals: 31,
    default: undefined,
    zeroFill: false,
    protocol41: true } ]
```

Comment: do console.log(wipeSQL) before conn.query and check what query is  getting build and passing to conn.query.Then fire this query manually on mysql query browser to see results.

Comment: @AJS Well, that was dumb.  Probably time to pass out tonight, the issue came down to replacing `.replace('%%DATABASE_NAME%%', conf['databasedatabase'])` with `.split('%%DATABASE_NAME%%').join(conf['databasedatabase'])` thanks, if you post an answer to this effect I'll accept it since you found it.

Comment: welcome...added as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do console.log(wipeSQL) before conn.query and check what query is getting build and passing to conn.query.Then fire this query manually on mysql query browser to see results.